# Using extern in C for functions

Tags: c, extern

If we have 2 source file and 1 header file of the same name for example

example.c which includes example.h and content is like above:

example.c

```
#include "example.h"

unsigned int add(unsigned int, unsigned int);

unsigned int add(unsigned int number1, unsigned int number2)
{
    return number1+number2;
}
```

example2.c

```
#include "example.h"

int main(void)
{
    add(2, 3);
}
```

example.h

```
#define SHIFT_LEFT_4(x) x*16 
#define SHIFT_LEFT_3(x) x*8 
#define SHIFT_LEFT_2(x) x*4

extern unsigned int add(unsigned int, unsigned int);
```

Is it okay to have two declarations of add function in example.c, one coming from example.h file as extern and one inside the source file, how the compiler will look at it? Is this done differently or that way is fine? I know that functions are extern by default, I just wrote it to explain easier the question.

Comment: Yes it is correct. But you can drop the `extern` for function declarations, it's useless. And the `unsigned int add(unsigned int, unsigned int);` in example.c is redundant, you should drop it. And you should also enclose macro parameters in (), like `#define SHIFT_LEFT_2(x) (x)*4`.

Comment: What about variables? If we have global variable and want also to use it in some other source file? Do we put it in header, then we have 2 declarations, similar situation like with functions.

Comment: Variables are not functions. With variables you need `extern`. You declare the global variable in exactly one .c file, and you use `extern` everywhere where you want to access this variable.

Comment: And it is correct to have the `extern` variable declaration (via inclusion of the header) and the definition is the .c file. Even netter, if you had incompatibilities, the compiler will notify you.

Comment: Is there any reason you make the "SHIFT_LEFT_..." macros so complicated. Just try `#define SHIFT_LEFT_4(x)  x << 4` or to be better prepared for different macro parameters or obstacles: `#define SHIFT_LEFT_4(x) ((x) << 4)`